# Habilitar SSL3 en java

Tags: java

Tengo un programa que se conecta a casillas de correo, a través de **IMAP**, pero hay algunas casillas de clientes que, cuando el programa intenta establecer la conexión, arroja la siguiente excepción:

> Server choose SSLv3, but that protocol version is not enabled or not
>   supported by the client.

Quisiera saber cómo puedo habilitar ese protocolo desde mi programa, si existe alguna propiedad o algo así que se pueda establecer. Ya busqué en varios lados pero no he dado con la solución.

La aplicación está hecha con **java 8 u66**.

Answer (score 3):

Ve a la carpeta de instalación del JRE

- Abre este archivo en un editor de texto: `$JRE_HOME\lib\security\java.security`
- Busca la linea que dice `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3` y coméntala o elimínala.

Luego vuelve a intentarlo.

Por cierto, tanto desde Java 8 update 31/Java 7 update 76 que SSLv3 viene deshabilitado por defecto. <sup>[1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u76-relnotes-2389087.html)</sup>

Cabe destacar que SSLV3 esta obsoleto y no deberia usarse salvo que sea absolutamente necesario debido a [vulnerabilidades](https://blogs.oracle.com/security/entry/information_about_ssl_poodle_vulnerability).

Comment: Probé ésto, pero sigue igual. Sólo con comentarla alcanza o hay que hacer algo así como una "recarga" de la configuración ?
Gracias.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Al final quité unas líneas del código, donde ponía que usara seguridad, y funcionó correctamente. Las líneas que saqué fueron las siguientes:

```
propiedades.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
propiedades.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.trust", servidor);
```

Al final el cliente no tenía habilitada la seguridad, pero el java me arrojaba como que estaba usando SSLv3.